# Render angular 2/4 template from server

Tags: angular, templates

I have started a project in angular-cli and want to pull in a remote html template from a Sitecore server (the markup in this template would need to contain Angular directives). Looking through various SO posts I have come up with the following approach.

The files I have look like this:

app.module.js

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './pages/about/about.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from './pages/privacy/privacy.component';

import { routes } from './app.router';

import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from './pipes/sanitise-html.pipe';

import { TemplateConfigService } from './services/template-config.service';
import { TemplateResolve } from './services/template-resolve';

import { InViewportModule } from 'ng-in-viewport';
// Remember to import `intersection-observer` polyfill to support all major browsers
import 'intersection-observer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,    
    AboutComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    SanitizeHtmlPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes,
    InViewportModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [TemplateConfigService,TemplateResolve],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

about.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  template: '<main [innerHtml]="myTemplate | sanitizeHtml"></main>'
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

public myTemplate: any = "";
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
   this.myTemplate = this.route.snapshot.data['tempURL'];
}

}
```

app.router.js

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './pages/about/about.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './pages/terms/terms.component';

import { TemplateResolve } from './services/template-resolve';

export const router: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, resolve: {tempURL: TemplateResolve}},
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, resolve: {tempURL: TemplateResolve} },
  { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent, resolve: {tempURL: TemplateResolve} },
  { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent, resolve: {tempURL: TemplateResolve} },
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent, resolve: {tempURL: TemplateResolve} },  
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

template-config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TemplateConfigService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getLocation(where:any) {

     let env = false
     let devString = 'http://localhost:3000/' + where; 
     let prodString =  '/' + where + '?ajax=true';
     let finalString = (env) ? prodString : devString;

     return this.http.get (finalString)
        .map ( response => { 
          return response [ '_body' ] 
        });

  }

}
```

template-resolve.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { TemplateConfigService } from './template-config.service';

@Injectable()
export class TemplateResolve implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(public tcs: TemplateConfigService) {}
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.tcs.getLocation(route.url[0].path);
  }
}
```

So basically I use the router to resolve the template markup before displaying the page, which is retrieved with an http.get call and inserted in the relevant place in the page. the 2 services facilitate this. using a simple express server for this example the code above fetches the template and displays the markup correctly, however the Angular directives within the code wont work. the markup itself is fairly trivial, in the snippets below, the *ngIf and (click) and routerLink wont work for example.

```
<a class="main-nav__link" routerLink="work" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="closeMenu()">Work</a>

<article class="card-blog card-blog--pink" *ngIf="filterBy!=='opinions'">
```

All the answers I have seen thus far seem to suggest this isn't possible as the template needs to be rendered locally before compilation ? Is there really no way to make this work, would appreciate any hacks or ideas anybody might have on this.

Comment: please move you question on dedicated Sitecore forum sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you reach a solution? Seems like a dead-end for me. I did not find a way yet!